# How to add a variable into a time series (ts) variable value while respecting the monthly frequency in R

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I want to know an simple and effective way to add a value into this time series variable while respecting the data frequency which is monthly buckets.

I am trying to create a average of the last 3 months of the time series variable and add that to the same variable and then calculate the next average of 3 months. And repeat it till I get the average of the upcoming 18 months.

```
library(dplyr)
library(forecast)
library(readxl)
library(data.table)
library(clock)
library(lubridate)
library(tsibble)

Sales_Actuals <- read_excel("C:/X/X/X/X.xlsx",
                            sheet = "File", skip = 3)


T_sales_Actuals <- data.table::transpose(Sales_Actuals,keep.names = "rn") %>% 
  setNames(.[1,]) %>% 
  slice(-1)

colnames(T_sales_Actuals)[1]="Date"
Dates <- T_sales_Actuals$Date

freq = 19

Output = data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow = freq,ncol = ncol(T_sales_Actuals)))
colnames(Output) <- colnames(T_sales_Actuals)


i = 1347
Y<- ts(data = T_sales_Actuals[,i],
       frequency = 12,
       start = c(2019,1),
       end = c(2023,7))
print(Y)

mean_val = mean(as.numeric(tail(Y,3)))
```

This is the data frame, I am dealing with:

```
structure(list(Date = c("2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-03-01", 
"2019-04-01", "2019-05-01", "2019-06-01", "2019-07-01", "2019-08-01", 
"2019-09-01", "2019-10-01", "2019-11-01", "2019-12-01", "2020-01-01", 
"2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", "2020-05-01", "2020-06-01", 
"2020-07-01", "2020-08-01", "2020-09-01", "2020-10-01", "2020-11-01", 
"2020-12-01", "2021-01-01", "2021-02-01", "2021-03-01", "2021-04-01", 
"2021-05-01", "2021-06-01", "2021-07-01", "2021-08-01", "2021-09-01", 
"2021-10-01", "2021-11-01", "2021-12-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-02-01", 
"2022-03-01", "2022-04-01", "2022-05-01", "2022-06-01", "2022-07-01", 
"2022-08-01", "2022-09-01", "2022-10-01", "2022-11-01", "2022-12-01", 
"2023-01-01", "2023-02-01", "2023-03-01", "2023-04-01", "2023-05-01", 
"2023-06-01", "2023-07-01", "2023-08-01"), `10ABC1|XYZ-ABC-PQR` = c("0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "213", "286", "472", "277", "332", "104", 
"45", "306", "316", "439", "263", "234")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-56L)
```

The `print(Y)` gives the below output:

[image]

I want to add the variable `mean_val` into this ts variable, as the value of Aug-2023.

Keep in mind, I dont want to mention the month as I have to repeat this for the next 18 months.